# WYSIWYG Editors Ripping Table Cells and Images on Save

Tags: tinymce, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have built a bespoke CMS in php and have used a wysiwyg editor to save description areas. For some reason when a table or an image is inserted they are not getting saved. On preview they seems to be fine however after the data is saved the edit seems to rip off the tables and images.

I have tried both CKEditor and Tinymce and have the same problem on both hence I am guessing this could be a database or server side error.

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed was that I had to go into settings and specifically tell tinymce to stop taking out the `<p>` and `<br />` in my code.

My tables were getting screwed up until I did that. While that might not be your specific problem, it might help to go through the advanced settings for your wysiwyg and check for things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your tinymce settings valid_elements and valid_children to find out if tinymce strips out your elements.